# Combining two Either of different types or dealing with Future and Either?

Tags: scala

I currently have the following methods :

```scala
/** EXISTING METHOD **/
 def getExcelFile(id: String) : EitherT[Future, AppError, File] = {

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Bank]
    val bank = findBank(id)

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, List[Services]]
    val services = EitherT(client.services(id))

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, List[AggregatedInformation]]
    val aggregateInfoFromSourceA = fromSourceA(id)

    (for {
      bankInfo <- bank 
      servicesList <- services
      result <- EitherT.right(exportService.source(bankInfo, servicesList, aggregateInfoFromSourceA))
    } yield {
      result
    }) 
 }
```

Now, I have this new method that I would like to add to the existing `for-comprehension`.

```scala
 def fromSourceB(accounts: List[Account], clients: List[Client]) : Future[List[AggregatedInformation]] = 
 {
     // Implementation here   
 }
```

The parameters `accounts` and `clients` come from two `EitherT` :

```scala
     // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Account]
    val accounts = findAccounts(id)

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Client]
    val clients = findClients(id)
```

What I'm trying to do, is to implement something like :

```scala
 def getExcelFile(id: String) : EitherT[Future, AppError, File] = {

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Bank]
    val bank = findBank(id)

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, List[Services]]
    val services = EitherT(client.services(id))

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, List[AggregatedInformation]]
    val aggregateInfoFromSourceA = fromSourceA(id)

     // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Account]
    val accounts = findAccounts(id)

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Client]
    val clients = findClients(id)

    // TODO 
    val aggregateInfoFromSourceB = aggregateInfo( ???, ???)

    (for {
      bankInfo <- bank 
      servicesList <- services
      sourceA <- aggregateInfoFromSourceA 
      sourceB <- aggregateInfoFromSourceB 
      result <- EitherT.right(exportService.source(bankInfo, servicesList, sourceA ::: sourceB))
    } yield {
      result
    }) 
 }
```

What I have done so far is to change the `aggregateInfo` method like this :

```scala
 def fromSourceB(accounts: List[Account], clients: List[Client]) : EitherT[Future, Nothing, List[AggregatedInformation]] = 
 {
     // Implementation here   
 }
```

and the `for-comprehension` as follow

```scala
 def getExcelFile(id: String) : EitherT[Future, AppError, File] = {

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Bank]
    val bank = findBank(id)

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, List[Services]]
    val services = EitherT(client.services(id))

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, List[AggregatedInformation]]
    val aggregateInfoFromSourceA = fromSourceA(id)

     // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Account]
    val accounts = findAccounts(id)

    // Returns EitherT[Future, AppError, Client]
    val clients = findClients(id)

    (for {
      bankInfo <- bank 
      servicesList <- services
      sourceA <- aggregateInfoFromSourceA 
      clientList <- clients
      accountList <- accounts
      sourceB <- aggregateInfoFromSourceB(clientList, accountList)
      result <- EitherT.right(exportService.source(bankInfo, servicesList, sourceA ::: sourceB))
    } yield {
      result
    }) 
 }
```

But I don't think this solution is really clean.
Is there any way to improve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by clean? What don't you like about current solution?

Comment: I'm pretty new to scala, and I was wondering if there was a better way to implement it. So far, I had to change the return type to `EitherT` and add a `EitherT.right()` to the return result. Not sure that this is the best way to do it. But maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: There is a lot of ways of implementing it differently but which one is better is subjective + case dependent.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, I'd like the `fromSourceB` to return only a `Future` and not an `Either` and then change something else so I can use the result in the `for-comprehension`

Comment: You could do: manual mapping of nested monads, monad transformers, tagless final or bifunctors run to `Future`. It is really depending on what you and your team already knows and what you find easy. Depending on you what you already know these solutions might be: boilerplaty or overcomplicated. Monad within a monad requires some trade offs.